# migrate successful but table does not exist

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to use flyway migrate oracle database, According to the official website said to operate,it seems migrate successful, but I can not found table in the database.

```
Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl (Oracle 11.2).
Validated 4 migrations (execution time 00:00.176s).
Current version of schema "lffair": 1.
Migrating schema "lffair" to version 1.0.1.
Migrating schema "lffair" to version 1.0.2.
Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "lffair" (execution time 00:00.181s).

sql>desc schema_version;
sql>Object schema_version does not exist.

sql>desc dept;
sql>Object dept does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the lffair schema. That's where the table was created.

Comment: Thaks for your answer! But i had look in the lffair schema and found no table in it.

Comment: The reason has been found,i remove parameter -schema from the flyway.properties,i went well.